# Mercurial via ssh, no repository found

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial, ssh

I've tried to install hg in my account of a pretty old ubuntu server (Ubuntu 10.04.4). It seems to work locally but I can't clone the repository via ssh.

```
$ hg clone ssh://user@server//home/user/path
```

give me a ".hg not found" error.

Yet,

```
$ ssh user@server 'ls /home/user/path/.hg'
```

works well.

Could it be a issue with ports ?
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Try adding `-v` and `--debug` to get more information.

Comment: This isn't really helpful :( `running ssh user@server 'hg -R /home/user/path serve --stdio'
sending hello command
sending between command
remote: abort : There is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found) !
abort : no suitable response from remote hg !`

Comment: Well, can you `ssh user@server` and then `cd /home/user/path; hg summary`. Is the repo on the server actually valid? Is `hg` installed ok?

Comment: `hg summary` works well. I can `hg clone /home/user/path` from an other directory locally on the server. hg version is 1.4.3 on the server and 2.1.2 on my machine. Thanks !

Comment: Large version difference there, but I wouldn't expect that to be an issue. I'm flummoxed!

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while, so this could be solved and unanswered.

Anyway, I have experienced the same problem when I installed Mercurial following [Per-user installation guide](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/UnixInstall). When I re-installed this as System-wide installation, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

should not be a port issue as long as you can ssh into the remote - had same issue with the following "out of order" setup:

- virtualenv with mercurial
- bashrc which alias hg=/path/to/virtenv/hg
- repository originally init with virtenv hg
- system-wide ubuntu 10.04 hg
  ---> gives the same error i.e. .hg not found

Solution:

- following steps on remote host
- backup your remote repos & update
- get rid of the virtenv & path alias
- logout & login ore make sure that .bashrc is reloaded and set
- remove .hg
- init & add & commit existing version using the system hg
- try to pull as usual - worked for me

Answer (score 1):

If you have hg somewhere non standard, eg ~/bin/hg just tell mercurial where to find it
hg clone ssh://you@remote/dir_to_clone --remotecmd bin/hg

This might happen if you're running an old distro like RHEL with systemwide mercurial installed but you've got more up to date version you run locally out of your home dir. Or perhaps you can't install systemwide software on the remote machine.

Give hg the --verbose flag to see the precise command it runs on the remote machine, make sure it uses the same hg instance as the one used to create the remote repo.

Old question, but I came here looking for the answer so might as well share it now I've solved it.

Comment: +1 for the --verbose; my actual problem was that I didn't have enough `/` characters, but the --verbose made it evident

Answer (score 1):

Also try the --verbose option as Hal mentioned.  In my case, this showed that the problem was I didn't have enough '/' characters before the path.

Failed:
`hg clone --verbose ssh://user@host/home/user/QFDC QFDC`

```
running ssh user@host "hg -R home/user/QFDC serve --stdio"
remote: abort: There is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found)!
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

Works - note double slash (`//`):
`hg clone --verbose ssh://user@host//home/user/QFDC QFDC`

```
running ssh user@host "hg -R /home/user/QFDC serve --stdio"
requesting all changes
adding changesets
...
```

This goes on to spew a lot of stuff, so you probably want to drop the `-R` once you get it working.